# Google api OVER_QUERY_LIMIT - how long

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I invoked google web service for distance too many times and now I can't call it because I receive error:

```
OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
```

Next time I will set pause on 10 call for 5 seconds. 
But how long I will be locked this way?

Comment: check this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#distance_matrix

Comment: i think it will block for 24hour

Answer (score 0):

2,500 geolocation requests per day => 1,250 seconds or 20 min 50 sec ([about limit see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits))

Answer (score 0):

I used to sleep 0,250 seconds between each request, this works well.
I tried 0,100 seconds but I got OVER_QUERY_LIMIT from time to time